# Custom View onDraw method is not getting called

Tags: android, view, android-canvas

I have a custom view which extends View. I am adding this to an activity as `setContent(..)` after creating its object, but its `onDraw()` is not getting called more than once. I know that it should be called infinitely.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: did you try to call `yourCustomViewInstance.invalidate();`

Comment: yes i tried.But as i know it will totally redraw my View which i dont want.

Comment: Suppose i draw a line.When i am drawing another line, the previous line is getting disappear.i line to be draw on touch.I already oveeride ontouch.

Comment: The above is happening when i am using invalidate();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android 2.2,2.3 tends to call onDraw a lot more than 3.0 and up.You should call onDraw yourself ,or invalidate() , when you want to create an animation or something and don't call it when you don't.

Comment: onDraw() is taking Canvas argument.How can i call whenever i want.

Comment: try with invalidate at the end of ondraw() or when you need refresh. Do it with a condition when you animating cause it will lag your app. Best solution is to try with surfaceview is your view is animating constantly

Comment: i know but the accept excuse ... Write your ondraw() method. invalidate at each frame when you need to animate is the right way and on draw() will be called as many times as you want

Comment: you actually not getting my point.I want ondraw to be called without clearing previous draw.

Comment: that cannot be done in canvas. You need surfaceview where you manualy have to clear the view. Canvas do this for you (actually in 90% of the cases that helps the programmer)